# Integral involving Legendre polynomial

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

In a physics problem the following integral shows up $$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}P_m(\cos{(\theta-\alpha)})\,\cos^{m+2}{(n\alpha)}\;d\alpha,$$ where $P_m$ is the Legendre polynomial and $n,m$ are integer numbers. How this integral can be evaluated?

Comment: I need to find if the following is true: for minimal m, for which the integral is not zero, it equals to $A\cos{(n\theta)}+B$, if n is odd, and it equals to $C\cos{(2n\theta)}+D$, if n is even, there A,B,C,D are some constants.

Comment: You mean not identical zero, or not zero for specific $\theta$?

Comment: Also it is non-zero for $m=0$, possibly you mean that $m, n$ are positive integers, at least $m$?

Comment: Not identicalLy zero. Yes,  $m,n$ are positive integers. If you use $\cos^{m+2}{(n\alpha)}=\sum\limits_s a^{(m+2)}_s\cos{((m+2-2s)n\alpha)}$ and  $P_m(\cos{(\theta-\alpha)})=\sum\limits_l b^{(m)}_l\cos^{m-2l}{(\theta-\alpha))}=\sum\limits_l\sum\limits_pb^{(m)}_la^{(m-2l)}_p\cos{(m-2l-2p)(\theta-\alpha)}$, it becomes clear that the integral is identically zero unless $(m+2-2s)n=m-2l-2p$.

Comment: The region $(m+2−2s)n=-(m−2l−2p)$ also contributes, and contributes exactly the same amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By periodicity of trigonometric functions we have
$$
I(m,n)=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}P_m(\cos{\alpha})\,\cos^{m+2}{(n\alpha+n\theta)}\;d\alpha.\tag{1}
$$
Moreover, by the symmetry of Legendre polynomials:
$$
I(m,n)=\left(1+(-1)^{mn+m}\right)\int\limits_0^{\pi}P_m(\cos{\alpha})\,\cos^{m+2}{(n\alpha+n\theta)}\;d\alpha.
$$
This last formula shows that the integral is $0$ when $m$ is odd, and $n$ is even:
$$
I(2M-1,2N)=0.
$$
Otherwise it is not useful.

Now in (1) we use the trigonometric expansion (Andrews, Askey, & Roy, 6.4.11):
$$
{P}_{m}\left(\cos \alpha\right)=
\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{(1/2)_k(1/2)_{m-k}}{k!(m-k)!}\cos(m-2k)\alpha,\quad \alpha\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
We also have
$$
(\cos x)^{2M+1}=\frac{1}{2^{2 M+1}}\sum_{j=-M}^{M+1}\binom{2 M+1}{j+M}\cos(2j-1)x,
$$
and
$$
(\cos x)^{2M}=\frac{1}{2^{2 M}}\sum_{j=-M}^{M}\binom{2 M}{j+M}\cos(2jx) .
$$
Using orthogonality of $\cos x$ on $(0,2\pi)$ we find:

$$
I(2M-1,2N+1)=\frac{\pi }{2^{2 M}}\sum_{j=-M}^{M+1}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{M+N-2Nj-j} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{M-N-1+2Nj+j}}{(M+N-2Nj-j)! (M-N-1+2Nj+j)!}\binom{2 M+1}{j+M}\cos\left[(2N+1)(2j-1)\theta\right].
$$

This formula has been checked numerically.

This formula seems like a major simplification compared with the double sums. The other cases are left as an exercise.

Comment: More convenient form: $$I(n,m)=\sum_{1+\lceil \frac{m(n-1)}{2n}\rceil}^{1+\lfloor \frac{m(n+1)}{2n}\rfloor}a^{m+2}_sC^m_{n(s-1)-\frac{m(n-1)}{2}}\cos{[(m+2-2s)n\theta]},$$ where $$C^n_k=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2(n-k)}{n-k},$$ and $a^n_k$ is given in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explicit formula for the value of this integral:

\begin{split}
&\frac{\pi}2 \sum_{s=1+\lceil\frac{m(n-1)}{2n}\rceil}^{m+2} \binom{m+2}s \cos(n(m+2-2s)\theta) \sum_{j=n(m+2-2s)}^{\lfloor \frac{m(n+1)}2\rfloor -n(s-1)} \frac1{2^{2j-n(m+2-2s)}} \\
&\times\binom{2j-n(m+2-2s)}j \binom{m}{2j-n(m+2-2s)}\binom{j+n(s-1)-\frac{m(n-1)+1}2}m.
\end{split}

Comment: I got (and verified numerically) a result that looks a little different: $$2\pi \sum_{s=1+\lceil\frac{m(n-1)}{2n}\rceil}^{1+\lfloor\frac{m(n+1)}{2n}\rfloor} a^{m+2}_s \cos(n(m+2-2s)\theta)\left (\sum_{l=0}^{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}b^m_la^{m-2l}_{n(s-1)-m(n-1)/2-l}\right).$$ Here $$a^n_m=2^{-n}\binom{n}{m},\;\;b^m_l=2^{-m}(-1)^l\binom{m}{l}\binom{2m-2l}{m}.$$ The result is valid if $m(n-1)$ is even. If $m(n-1)$ is odd, the integral is zero.

Comment: If $\lceil \frac{m(n-1)}{2n}\rceil > \lfloor \frac{m(n+1)}{2n}\rfloor$, the integral is zero.